How do I add default wallpaper for landscape and portrait accordingly?
I'm customizing AOSP source. I have two images for different resolutions for my tablet. The images are: One for landscape and the other for portrait.
How do I change the images for the wallpaper when the configuration changes?
Additional comment:
I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, so I'm writing here.
I've already tried drawable-port, drawable-land, drawable-... etc. But it didn't work. The wallpaper of AOSP doesn't follow this rule. If orientation change happens, wallpaper bitmap is internally rotated and zoomed. I can't find the source code to fix it... it's too complicated and there's no document.

Put this images into orientation depend directories, for example:
Resource dir name for portait mode: drawable-port
and for landscape mode: drawable-land
Example path where default_wallpaper of aosp14 system is placed:
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png
Check out other drawable variants also.
